# How to use $mod operator from mongodb in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I checked the usage of `$mod` operator in mongo, but I could not find how to query the same using Golang.

Usage in mongo:

```
{fieldName:{$mod:[24,0]}}
```

Expecting the usage in Golang

Answer (score 1):

You can directly translate that to a `bson.M` object:

```
bson.M{"fieldName":bson.M{"$mod":[]int{24,0}}}
```

Comment: This is working, just changed the separator 
bson.M{"fieldName":bson.M{"$mod":[]int{24,0}}}